# What are the Yoshi Egg medals for?

Tags: yoshis-new-island

I noticed that if you complete a level and the flower roulette lands on a flower, you get a number of Yoshi medals matching the number of flowers you got in a level. What are these medals for? It right now says x/30 medals for world 1, and I am not sure what that means or if I can use the medals for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The medals are for a bonus game that you can find at the bottom right corner of the touchpad's screen. If you collect enough medals, you can press the bonus level and play one of Yoshi's vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

if you collect all 30, you unlock a challenge level. There is a new level for each world.

Comment: "All 30"? Meaning I have to both collect all the flowers, then be lucky enough to land on one in the goal roulette? That's annoying...